# random date sorting is not working in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, random, excel-formula

I wrote a function in Excel `=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2019,1,1),DATE(2022,10,31))` and got the column filled with random dates but now I have to arrange them in oldest to newest order even after sorting I am getting random dates but not in order of sorting from oldest to newest. why so?

I tried the sorting option, and also tried copy past in another column and then sorting but both didn't work.

Comment: `why so?` - because the function recalculates after each sort?

Comment: If your Excel version supports it, consider using `RANDARRAY` and `SORT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `=SORT(RANDARRAY(10,1,DATE(2019,1,1),DATE(2022,10,31),TRUE))`
where `10` is the number of dates you wish to sort

Answer (score 1):

One could use the following:

```
=LET(x, DATE(2019,1,1), y, DATE(2022,10,31), SORT(RANDARRAY(y-x+1,,x,y,1)))
```

---

Using `DATE(2019,1,1)` as start date & `DATE(2022,10,31)` as end date returns `1400` records.

---

To make it shorter and have some `31` records with unique, one can use this as well:

```
=LET(x, DATE(2019,1,1), y, DATE(2022,10,31), z, SORT(RANDARRAY(y-x+1,,x,y,1)), UNIQUE(TAKE(z, 31)))
```

---